# Why doesn't my CSS animation work in Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The animation works just fine in Firefox, but when I tested it on Chrome and Chromium, it didn't work.

```css
div.rocket {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: rocket;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.9,.03,.69,.22);
  text-align:center;
}
img.rocket {
  height: 5%;
  width: 5%;
}

@keyframes rocket {
  0% {
    top: 140%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 1vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rocket">
  <img class="rocket" src="//mason1920.github.io/rocket/img/rocket.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Please review [ask] and update your question to include a [mcve] otherwise it is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._"

Comment: Does this count?

Comment: @user7376137 yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would need to use the same unit for all keyframe values. You can not have one value as `%` and other as `vh`. This [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) blog post might help.

```css
div.rocket {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: rocket;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.9,.03,.69,.22);
  text-align:center;
}
img.rocket {
  height: 5%;
  width: 5%;
}

@keyframes rocket {
  0% {
    top: 45vh;
  }
  100% {
    top: 1vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rocket">
  <img class="rocket" src="//mason1920.github.io/rocket/img/rocket.svg">
</div>
```